# How do I determine what app is currently in the foreground?

Tags: java, android, logging, android-activity

I need a way to log what app is currently running in the foreground, preferably without requiring root access or using the NDK. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, onResume() gets triggered any time an activity gets on foreground. If your app contains more than one activity, you should check all of them.

You can check activities lifecycle [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Comment: Hmmm. So I would just need to be able to access the logcat?

Comment: ooops, I'm afraid I misunderstood your question.. I thought you were asking to see wether YOUR app was on foreground. Sorry again..

Comment: No, I'm trying to make an app that tracks productive time vs time off task.